# When to flush a BufferedWriter

Tags: java, io

In a Java program (Java 1.5), I have a BufferedWriter that wraps a Filewriter, and I call write() many many times... The resulting file is pretty big...

Among the lines of this file, some of them are incomplete...

Do I need to call flush each time I write something (but I suspect it would be inefficient) or use another method of BufferedWriter or use another class...?

(Since I've a zillion lines to write, I do want to have something quite efficient.)
What would be the ideal "flushing" moment? (when I reach the capacity of the BufferedWriter)...

Init:

```
try {
  analysisOutput = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
      "analysisResults", true));
  analysisOutput.newLine();
  analysisOutput.write("Processing File " + fileName + "\n");
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Writing:

```
private void printAfterInfo(String toBeMoved,HashMap<String, Boolean> afterMap, Location location)
  throws IOException {
    if(afterMap != null) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> map : afterMap.entrySet()) {
        if (toBeMoved == "Condition") {
          if (1 <= DEBUG)
            System.out.println("###" + toBeMoved + " " + location + " "
                + conditionalDefs.get(conditionalDefs.size() - 1)
                + " After " + map.getKey() + " "
                + map.getValue() + "\n");

          analysisOutput.write("###" + toBeMoved + " " + location + " "
              + conditionalDefs.get(conditionalDefs.size() - 1)
              + " After " + map.getKey() + " " + map.getValue()
              + "\n");
        } else {
          if (1 <= DEBUG)
            System.out.println("###" + toBeMoved + " " + location + " "
                + map.getKey() + " After " 
                + map.getValue() + "\n");
          if (conditionalDefs.size() > 0)
            analysisOutput.write("###" + toBeMoved + " " + location + " "
                + conditionalDefs.get(conditionalDefs.size() - 1) + " "
                + map.getKey() + " After " + map.getValue()
                + "\n");
          else
            analysisOutput.write("###" + toBeMoved + " " + location + " " + map.getKey() + " After " + map.getValue() + "\n");


        }
      }
    }
```

I've just figured out that the lines which are incomplete are those just before "Processing file"... so it occurs when I'm switching from one file that I analyze to another...

Closing:

```
dispatch(unit);

try {
  if (analysisOutput != null) {
    printFileInfo();
    analysisOutput.close();
  }
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sometimes the information printed out by printFileInfo does not appear in the results file...

Comment: If some are incomplete, do you have multiple threads writing to it?  IIRC a BufferedWriter is NOT thread-safe, so that could be an explanation, but it does NOT have to be "flushed manually" to make more room, it takes care of that itself.

Comment: If you're not sure you question is clear, perhaps provide a code sample or output sample that clarifies.

Comment: It is actually thread-safe (although Writer decorators have issues about agreeing on what object to lock).

Comment: How to be sure that this is thread safe ? I'm writing in a static file and using make -j (which i guess is multi-threaded...
)

Comment: I would look for a bug in the printFileInfo() method.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The `BufferedWriter` will already flush when it fills its buffer. From the docs of [`BufferedWriter.write`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write):

> Ordinarily this method stores characters from the given array into this stream's buffer, 
>   *flushing the buffer to the underlying stream as needed*.

(Emphasis mine.)

The point of `BufferedWriter` is basically to consolidate lots of little writes into far fewer big writes, as that's usually more efficient (but more of a pain to code for). You shouldn't need to do anything special to get it to work properly though, other than making sure you flush it when you're *finished* with it - and calling `close()` will do this and flush/close the underlying writer anyway.

In other words, relax - just write, write, write and close :) The only time you normally need to call `flush` manually is if you really, really need the data to be on disk now. (For instance, if you have a perpetual logger, you might want to flush it every so often so that whoever's reading the logs doesn't need to wait until the buffer's full before they can see new log entries!)

Comment: Tested & Approved. Writed 10Mb of numbers line by line: flushing after write each line - takes 7 seconds, without flushing - 4 seconds.

Answer (score 14):

The ideal flushing moment is when you need another program reading the file to see the data that's been written, before the file is closed. In many cases, that's never.

Comment: even if the BufferedWriter is big...I don't have to do it at an intermediate stage ?

Comment: If the buffer fills up, it will write out its contents to disk. The BufferedWriter API is designed to be a drop-in replacement for a FileWriter, with the exception of consuming data before the file is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a loop alternating `init` and `printAfterInfo`, my guess about your problem is that you don't `close` your writer before creating a new one on the same file. You'd better create the `BufferedWriter` once and close it at the end of all the processing.