# Writing even and odd numbers to a dat file

Tags: java, file-io

I have started learning Java and am having problem with a simple program that should write some content to `numbers.dat` file.

I am facing two problems:

1. The output that I am getting is as follows:

   > 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90, 110, 132, 156, 182, 210, 240, 272, 306, 342, 380, 420, 462, 506, 552, 600, 650, 702, 756, 812, 870, 930, 992, 1056, 1122, 1190, 1260, 1332, 1406, 1482, 1560, 1640, 1722, 1806, 1892, 1980, 2070, 2162, 2256, 2352, 2450, 2550...

   When it should be:

   For even numbers:

   > 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,……,98,100

   For odd numbers:

   > 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,……,98,100,1,3,5,7,9,……..97,99
2. My second problem is that the output is not getting written to `numbers.dat` file! It's all blank.

The question from the book that I am trying to solve is:

> Write a program called TextFileIO.java to create a file named numbers.dat. Then create an algorithm that writes all even numbered integers from 1 to 100, separated by a comma.
>
> After the file has been created, close and reopen the file and display the results to the screen. After the results have been displayed append the odd number integers from 1 to 100, separated by a comma to the end of the file. Reopen the file and display the results. The contents of the file should be the even numbers from 1 to 100 separated by a comma followed by the odd number from 1 to 100 separated by a comma. The output of this program would be something like the following:
>
> 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,……,98,100
>
> 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,……,98,100,1,3,5,7,9,……..97,99

Below is the code that I have tried so far:

**textFileIO.java**

```
package package1;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

//class definition
public class textFileIO{

    //The main function
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //This declares a file to open.
        File outFile = new File("numbers.dat");

        int sumEven = 0;
        int sumOdd = 0;

        //File IO requires a try/catch block to prevent the program from crashing
        try {

            //a buffered writer is used to allow us to write to the file.
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));

            //This for loop handles adding all of the numbers together
            for(int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) {
                sumEven += i + 1;
                writer.write("" + sumEven + ", ");
            }

            //adding a new line and closing the file
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();

            //A buffered Reader is used for reading a new file.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outFile));

            //Because I only add a new line at the end, I only need to read the first line.
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());

            //I need to write again, so I close the reader and open the writer.
            reader.close();

            //you need to create another object to append to the file
            //writer.open();
            BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));

            //This for loop is identical to the previous one, except for odd numbers
            for(int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) {
                sumOdd += i;
                writer2.write("" + sumOdd + ", ");
            }

            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();

            //The same here. You need to create another reader
            //reader.open();
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outFile));
            System.out.println(reader2.readLine());

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

I changed my code and this is my latest code. I am still having problems.
The console output screen is showing 49 and 50 as output and my numbers.dat file is now showing only comma separated list of odd numbers. What am I doing wrong now?

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class TextFileIO {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            //Clear the contents of numbers.dat if already exists and populated
            File fileOne = new File("numbers.dat");
            fileOne.delete();
            File newFile = new File("numbers.dat");
            newFile.createNewFile();
            //Create writer object
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"));
            //Loop from 1 to 100
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                //If number is even, write to file  
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    writer.print(i + ",");
                }
            }
            //Close writer object.
            writer.close();
            //Read from file
            FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fileStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            //Print line
            System.out.println(reader.read());
            reader.close();
            //Write all odd numbers to file
            PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"));
            //Loop from 1 to 100
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                //If number is odd, write to file  
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    writer2.print(i + ",");
                }
            }
            writer2.close();
            //Read from file
            FileInputStream fileStream2 = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
            DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(fileStream2);
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));
            //Print line
            System.out.println(reader2.read());
            reader.close();
        }
     
     
    }
```

**Edit 3:** I am still unable to get the desired output. I am still getting the output in console as 49 and 50, and in numbers.dat file, the output is still only odd numbers separated by commas. I am unable to understand what exactly to change in my code.

Comment: You ar defining writer2 to be created of your file but you are closing writer! writer.newLine(); writer.close(); If you want to write even numbers or odd numbers you have to increase SumeEven with 2 not with i!

Comment: So, where should I close writer then?

Comment: After the first loop you are closing writer. Then you are creating writer2 but after the second loop you are closing the writer instead of writer2. I think it is just a copy-paste error. Because you have already closed writer once!

Comment: @Govan: can you please check my updated code and comment?

Comment: @Serenity accept an answer if that has helped you getting the desired outcome?

Comment: @Bharat : I have tried all answers given by you guys. I am still stuck. Its the same output I am getting. What exactly should i change now??

Comment: @Serenity.. my final attempt... you should get all the numbers now... just handle extra comma and new line if you want!!! and this time accept an answer :)

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream if you want to read text, its more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the correct number to print you should change

Even number loop:

```
//This for loop handles adding all of the numbers together
for(int i = 2; i <=100; i += 2) {
writer.write("" + i + ", ");
}
```

Odd number loop:

```
//This for loop is identical to the previous one, except for odd numbers
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) {
writer2.write("" + i + ", ");
}
```

And replace your following statement:

```
System.out.println(reader.read());
```

with

```
System.out.println(reader.readLine());
```

and you should be done.

## EDIT

```
public class textFileIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Clear the contents of numbers.dat if already exists and populated
        File fileOne = new File("numbers.dat");
        fileOne.delete();
        File newFile = new File("numbers.dat");
        newFile.createNewFile();
        //Create writer object
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"));
        //Loop from 1 to 100
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            //If number is even, write to file  
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                writer.print(i + ",");
            }
        }
        //Close writer object.
        writer.close();
        //Read from file
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fileStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        //Print line
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        reader.close();
        //Write all odd numbers to file
        PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"));
        //Loop from 1 to 100
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            //If number is odd, write to file  
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                writer2.print(i + ",");
            }
        }
        writer2.close();
        //Read from file
        FileInputStream fileStream2 = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
        DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(fileStream2);
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));
        //Print line
        System.out.println(reader2.readLine());
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly for me and here is the output...

> 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,
>   1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97,99,

Comment: try the new one... you should be printing `i` instead of `sumEven`

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. For the second writer (writer2), you need to pass in a "true" value in the FileWriter constructor.  Otherwise, it will simply overwrite outfile with new content (see [FileWriter Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29))

   PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"**, true**));
2. As Govan mentioned, you're not closing writer2.  This is why your file is blank.  If you call writer2.close, the BufferedWriter's "flush" method gets called.  "flush" is what actually forces the writer to write data into the file ([When to Flush a BufferedWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908168/when-to-flush-a-bufferedwriter)).
3. As Bharat mentioned, you should re-write your loops to use the "i" variable to write, not sumEven.  The way you sumEven is written, you'll get the following:

   i=1, sumEven = sumEven + i + 1 = 0 + 1 + 1 = 2

   i=3, sumEven = sumEven + i + 1 = 2 + 3 + 1 = 6

   i=5, sumEven = sumEven + i + 1 = 6 + 5 + 1 = 12

   ...

Comment: Hi..I have updated my code..can you please comment on thta? I am now having some new problems..It IS now writing to file but otput is not what I want :(

Comment: You're almost there.  You just need to make sure that the second writer appends to the end of numbers.dat, rather than writing from the  beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

your first loop can be like this

```
for (i = 0; i < 100 ; i+2)
{ 
   if (i != 0) {
    writer.print(", ");
   } 
    writer.print(i+2);
}
```

the second shall be like this

```
for (i = 0; i < 100 ; i+2)
{ 
    writer.print( ", " +(i+1));
}
```

Otherwise you have to go an extra comma on the end of line!

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of changes to your code.

First you don't need two writers, neither do you need two readers.

Your single writer can write both even and odd numbers since you are only writing to one file. The scenario where I will consider two writers is if your are writing an odd file and an even file separately, concurrently.

Anyway, I just commented out the fluff stuff. If you delete all the comments, the code should be simpler, works and most especially more readable.

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class TextFileIO {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            //Clear the contents of numbers.dat if already exists and populated
            File fileOne = new File("numbers.dat");
            fileOne.delete();
            File newFile = new File("numbers.dat");
            newFile.createNewFile();
            //Create writer object
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"));
            //Loop from 1 to 100
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                //If number is even, write to file  
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    writer.print(i + ",");
                }
            }
            //Close writer object.
            //writer.close();
            //Read from file
            //FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
            //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fileStream);
            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            //Print line
            //System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            //reader.close();
            //Write all odd numbers to file
            //PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"));
            //Loop from 1 to 100
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                //If number is odd, write to file  
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    writer.print(i + ",");
                }
            }
            writer.close();
            //Read from file
            FileInputStream fileStream2 = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
            DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(fileStream2);
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));
            //Print line
            System.out.println(reader2.readLine());
            reader2.close();
        }


    }
```

Cleaning up the code a bit, you get the below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TextFileIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Clear the contents of numbers.dat if already exists and populated
        File fileOne = new File("numbers.dat");
        fileOne.delete();
        File newFile = new File("numbers.dat");
        newFile.createNewFile();
        //Create writer object
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"));
        //Loop from 1 to 100
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            //If number is even, write to file  
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                writer.print(i + ",");
            }
        }
        //Loop from 1 to 100
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            //If number is odd, write to file  
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                writer.print(i + ",");
            }
        }
        writer.close();
        //Read from file
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fileStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        //Print line
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        reader.close();
    }
}
```