# Writing a string array to file using Java - separate lines

Tags: java, arrays, string, file-io

I'm writing a program that writes sets of observations in the form of a String array (from User input) to file. I am able to write an observation to a .txt file and then add a new observation without removing the previous data, but all my data is on the same line. **I need each set of observations to be on a separate line.** Additionally I will need to be able to access the file later on and read from it.

My code currently looks like this: (observation is the string array)

```
for(int i = 0; i < observation.length; i++) {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("birdobservations.txt", true))) {
        String s;
        s = observation[i];
        bw.write(s);
        bw.flush();
    } catch(IOException ex) {}  
}
```

My output currently looks like this: `CrowMOsloMay2015JayMOsloJune2012CrowMOsloMay2015RobinFBergenMay2012`

I would like it to look like this:

```
Crow M Oslo May2015

Jay M Oslo June2012
```

...etc

How do I do this? I assume I need some kind of loop, but I've been stuck on figuring this out for a while now.

Comment: Where are you printing spaces and  newlines? `write` only writes the string you give it.

Comment: Don't flush after writing a couple of bytes! You're using a BufferedWriter that decides itself on when to flush. See here for example: [When to flush a BufferedWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908203/688182)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not iterate within your `try{}` block and use [BufferedWriter.newLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) after each write ?

If you need to be able to read the values back in later, you need to consider some unambiguous output format. Perhaps the simplest solution is a CSV format (I note your output data has spaces - you would need to separate your entries using something other than spaces in that case)

Comment: Ok, so .newLine seems to be correct...in a way...

It separates each part of the array with a new line though, so maybe I should just leave it that way. 

Unfortunately we have to use a .txt file for the assignment.

Comment: Although you call it .txt, there's no reason why it can't contain comma separated values, is there ?

Comment: I guess I hadn't considered that. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to push a line separator into the buffer.

```
newLine();
```

Here's the code

```
for(int i = 0; i < observation.length; i++) {
  try (BufferedWriter bw 
        = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("birdobservations.txt", true))) {
    String s;
    s = observation[i];
    bw.write(s);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
  } catch(IOException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: This answers the question perfectly. It might also be nice to iterate inside the try so you don't have to make a new BufferedWriter for every record.

Answer (score 0):

```
bw.write(s);
bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
bw.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 bw.write(s);
bw.newLine();
bw.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment [Brian Agnew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12960/brian-agnew)'s answer because of my reputation, so I write it here.

Seems you never have any spaces in your array items, so you can successfully use them as a separators in your .txt file.
When reading, just read the file line by line and separate items by [split(" ")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.