# Writing an array of strings to a file - one line?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file-io

Here is an example where I read lines from a file as strings to make a whole file as an array of strings:

```
String[] ArrayOfStrings = (new Scanner( new File("log.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next()).split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

I there any similar way to do the write back into the file:

```
something_that_writes_into_file(ArrayOfStrings)?
```

I know about `PrintWriter`, `Buffer` and other stuffs using loops.

My question is specifically about something which is more compact, say - a one line solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) and [Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(theFile), StringUtils.join(theArray, delimiter));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done.

```
for(int i = 0; i < observation.length; i++)
{
    try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("birdobservations.txt", true)))
    {
        String s;
        s = observation[i];
        bw.write(s);
        bw.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Same question is discussed before, Please refer below link for the same.
[Writing a string array to file using Java - separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871341/writing-a-string-array-to-file-using-java-separate-lines)

Answer (score 0):

In Java8 one might use Streams:

```
File file = new File("log.txt");
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);

// reading
String[] arrayOfStrings = (new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\A").next()).split("[\\r\\n]+");

// writing
Stream.of(arrayOfStrings).forEach(e -> {try {out.append(e);} catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}});
```

Of couse this is very bad style and I only wrote it that way, because you requested a "1-liner". Actually it would be done like so:

```
Stream.of(arrayOfStrings).forEach(e -> {
    try {
        out.append(e);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```