# How to take array input from a file ,sort it and display output in the same file

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, exception, user-input

I have taken array input from a file "File.txt"( which is having first input as size of the array(4) and next inputs are numbers which i have to sort) and sorted the array but now I want to print the sorted array a[i] in the same file "File.txt"

Till now I have done this....when I run it in console by taking array input from the file "File.txt" it runs properly but when I want to display the outputs in the same file it says...array out of bounds exception
How can I do this??

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f1);
    int [] a = new int[sc.nextInt()];

    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    int temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<a.length-1;j++)
     {
       if(a[j]>a[j+1])
       {
         temp=a[j];
         a[j]=a[j+1];
         a[j+1]=temp;
       }
     }
    }
    FileWriter fw = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

     try
      {

        fw = new FileWriter(f1,true);  
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);            
        pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

        pw.println(a[i]);


      }
     catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
          try
          {
           fw.close();
           bw.close();
           pw.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are u printing`a[i]` out?

Comment: What do you suppose `i` contains when the program reaches the line `pw.println(a[i])`?  Also, shouldn't that line be in a loop of some kind?

Comment: sorry for that...A big mistake..but when i use a loop there still it shows array out of bound exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are printing `a[i]`.
You use the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
```

After this loop, `i` is equal to `a.length`. 
Then in another line you call

```
pw.println(a[i]);
```

to output in the file. But now `i` refers to an element which out of the bound of the array.
You have to output it by iterating like this:

```
  BufferedWriter bw = null;
  bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f1));
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    bw.write(Integer.toString(a[i]);
    bw.newLine();
  }
  bw.flush();  
  bw.close();
```

Comment: Sir....What if I don't use bw.flush() and bw.close().....what will happen..It actually not showing the output if i dont use them...What is the proper use of it.

Comment: Can I just take numbers as input from the mixed string and numbers from a file ??

Comment: @AmitKumar You need to flush and write if you want to have the data on the disk. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908168/when-to-flush-a-bufferedwriter. If this has solved your problem, mark it as the answer and upvote please.